# Bootstrap - How to align vertically the divs

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have this list of user inputs. I want to align vertically the items.
I don't know neighter if I'm doing this on the right way.

How can I do to proceed it without using tables?

[image]

```
    <div class="card-body">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
         <span class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="col-md-auto"><i class="nav-icon fas fa-hard-hat"></i> Montador</div>
         </span>
         <span class="input-group-prepend"><button class="btn btn-info btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button></span><input class="form-control input-number" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="4" type="number" value="0"><span class="input-group-prepend"><button class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
         <span class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="col-md-auto"><i class="nav-icon fas fas fa-book"></i> Meio-Oficial</div>
         </span>
         <span class="input-group-prepend"><button class="btn btn-info btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button></span><input class="form-control input-number" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="4" type="number" value="0"><span class="input-group-prepend"><button class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></span>
      </div>
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify column size to keep them uniform. Also, don't use input groups where they aren't needed, and use labels for each input with `for` attributes associating them with their inputs.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#form-grid

[Lots of similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+4+align+input+labels+site:stackoverflow.com)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="card-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <label class="mb-3" for="input1"><i class="nav-icon fas fa-hard-hat"></i> Montador</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>   
          </span>

          <input class="form-control input-number" id="input1" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="4" type="number" value="0">

          <span class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <label class="mb-3" for="input2"><i class="nav-icon fas fa-hard-hat"></i> Montador</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>   
          </span>

          <input class="form-control input-number" id="input2" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="4" type="number" value="0">

          <span class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <label class="mb-3" for="input3"><i class="nav-icon fas fa-hard-hat"></i>  Meio-Oficial</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>   
          </span>

          <input class="form-control input-number" id="input3" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="4" type="number" value="0">

          <span class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```